What is the point of taking out the coefficient "a" in the derivative problem d/dx(af(x))?
So it's been a few years since i've taken calculus and I'm a bit rusty. This is one of the derivative rules taught in khan academy. My question is what is even the point to taking out that coefficient in front of the function? If I recall correctly in ap calc we wouldn't bother taking out the 2 in this example. Intuitively we would just bring down the five to multiply it with the 2 and decrease the power by one. It results in the same derivative 10x^4. Is there any case where I would absolutely need to take out that coefficient? I don't mind doing it if it's the correct way to do this type of derivative problem but I just wanted to make sure.

I don't really understand the question. The point is that $\tfrac{d}{dx}(af(x))=a\tfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$ is a theorem of calculus which is quite handy together with e.g. the theorem $\tfrac{d}{dx}(x^\alpha)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$.

@stochastic-conch Yes I understand it is a theorem of calculus but why is it important if the power rule can just as easily be applied? For example the derivate of 14x^2 is just 28x. All I did was multiply the 14 by 2 and decrease the power by one. It seems like taking out the constant is just an extra step that isn't needed. So my question is what applications does this have that couldn't be solved with the power rule? Sorry for the question but it has been almost 5 years since I've taken calculus

I am sure Khan academy will at some point teach to take derivatives of slightly more complicated functions than powers of $x,.$ Then the ability to take out the constant will most likely matter more.

The beauty of the take-out-the-constant rule is that it’s so intuitive you can use it without having to think about it.

When the power rule is usually taught, technically all that has been proven is that $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n) = nx^{n-1}$$ for a monic polynomial $x^n$ that is, a polynomial with leading coefficient of one. The theorem doesn't stand for powers of $x$ with a coefficient. One must prove separately that given a non-monic polynomial $ax^{n}$ that its derivative is given by $$\frac{d}{dx}(ax^{n}) = anx^{n-1},$$ which can only be proven by first applying the constant factor rule and then the power rule to the monic polynomial:
For any real number $a$ and positive integer $n$,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(ax^n) = a \frac{d}{dx}(x^n) = a(nx^{n-1}) = anx^{n-1}$$
Once that rule has been established, then indeed we can proceed by just applying the power rule from the get-go.

I agree that this is the usual way things are taught, and it is my prefered one, but it is not true that "$\frac{d}{dx}(ax^{n}) = anx^{n-1}$ can only be proven by first applying the constant factor rule and then the power rule to the monic polynomial". It can as well be proved directly, and taught as easily instead of just $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{n}) = nx^{n-1}$.

It can also be derived from Leibniz' rule and differentiation of monic polynomials.
